# Passing Jackjson JSON object from JSP to JavaScript function

Tags: java, javascript, json

I have a JSON String stored in a database. In one of my JSP pages, I retrieve this string, and I want to be able to pass the String or the JSON object into Javascript function. The function is simply this for test purposes

```
function test(h){

alert(h);
}
```

Now I can retrieve the JSON string from the database fine, I have printed it out to the screen to ensure that it is getting it, however when I pass it in like this

```
        <input  type="button" 
                                name="setFontButton" 
                                value="Set" 
                                class="form_btn_primary"
                                onclick="test('<%=theJSON%>'); return false;"/>
```

Nothing happens. I used firebug to check what was wrong, and it says there is invalid character.

So I then tried passing in the JSON object like so

```
Widget widg = mapper.readValue(testing.get(0), Widget.class);
```

Then pass in it

```
onclick="test('<%=widg%>'); return false;"/>
```

Now this will pass in without an error, and it alerts the object name, however I am unable to parse it. Object comes in like with the package name of where the widget class is stored like so

```
com.package.mode.Widget@ba8af9
```

I tried using Stringify, but that doesn't seem to work on this Jackson JSON object.

After all that failed, I tried a last resort of taking the String from the database, and encoding it in base64. However, this too fails if I do this

```
String test = Base64.encode(theString);
```

and pass that in. However if I do that, print it out to the screen, then copy what is printed out, and send that through it works, so don't quite understand why that is.

So could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. I have tried soo many different solutions and nothing is working.

The JSON String is stored in database like this

> {
>      "id":1,
>      "splits":[
>         {
>            "texts":[
>               {
>                  "value":"Test",
>                  "locationX":3,
>                  "locationY":-153,
>                  "font":{
>                     "type":"Normal",
>                     "size":"Medium",
>                     "bold":false,
>                     "colour":"5a5a5a",
>                     "italics":false
>                  }
>               }
>            ]
>         }
>      ]
>   }

Would be very grateful if someone could point me in the direct direction!!

Edit:

Incase anyone else has same problem do this to pass the JSON from JSP to the JS function

```
<%=theJSON.replaceAll("\"", "\\\'")%>
```

That allows you to pass the JSON in,

then to get it back in JavaScript to normal JSON format

```
theJSON = theJSON.replace(/'/g,'"');
```

Should work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the combination of double quotes wrapping the onclick and the ones in your JSON may be messing you up. Think of it as if you entered the JSON manually -- it would look like this:

```
onclick="test('{ "id":1, "splits":[ { "texts":[ { "value":"Test", "locationX":3, "locationY":-153, "font":{ "type":"Normal", "size":"Medium", "bold":false, "colour":"5a5a5a", "italics":false } } ] } ] }'); return false;"
```

and the opening double quote before `id` would actually be closing the double quote following `onclick=` (You should be able to verify this by looking at the page source). Try specifying the onclick as:

```
onclick='test(\'<%=theJSON%>\'); return false;'
```

Comment: You were along the right lines, had to escape it, just grabbed it from database then escaped it using replaceAll command, then passed the new string into the javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following steps

1. Fetch the jon string
2. Using the jackson or any other JSON jar file , convert the json string to json array and print the string using out.println.
3. Call this jsp  which prints the json string
4. check in the firebug , you will be able to see your json .
5. If the Json string does not print , there can be some problems in your json format.

this is a good website for json beautification , http://jsbeautifier.org/ , really makes the string simple to read .

Thanks
Abhi